# Using the GHC API to do a "dry run" of code compilation

Tags: haskell, ghc, static-analysis, dynamic-compilation, ghc-api

I'm working on a fairly simple text-editor for Haskell, and I'd like to be able to highlight static errors in code when the user hits "check."

Is there a way to use the GHC-API to do a "dry-run" of compiling a haskell file without actually compiling it? I'd like to be able to take a string and do all the checks of normal compilation, but without the output. The GHC-API would be ideal because then I wouldn't have to parse command-line output from GHC to highlight errors and such.

In addition, is it possible to do this check on a string, instead of on a file? (If not, I can just write it to a temp file, which isn't terribly efficient, but would work).

If this is possible, could you provide or point me to an example how how to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242986/need-a-tutorial-for-using-ghc-to-parse-and-typecheck-haskell) ask the same thing, but it is from three years ago, at which time the answer was "GHC-API is new and there isn't good documentation yet." So my hope is that the status has changed.

EDIT: the "dry-run" restriction is because I'm doing this in a web-based setting where compilation happens server side, so I'd like to avoid unnecessary disk reads/write every time the user hits "check". The executable would just get thrown away anyways, until they had a version ready to run.

Comment: I would consider it a added *feature* to get both errors annotated *and* get a working executable from my IDE, but that is just me :)

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. I'm doing a browser-based thing where they write their code in an editor and it gets stored in a database. I can't divulge too much yet, but it's less of an IDE, but the project involves users submitting code which is run server-side. (SafeHaskell makes this nice and safe.) So, I guess it would be enough to compile it and just throw away the executable, but it seems like extra overhead, especially on a server-side app which could be running multiple compilations at once.

Comment: Take a look at ghc-mod. It's designed for just this

Comment: Add this as an answer and I'll accept it. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to move this to an answer, this already exists as [ghc-mod](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-mod), here's the [homepage](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/). This already has frontends for Emacs, Sublime, and Vim so if you need examples of how to use it, there are plenty. In essence ghc-mod is just what you want, a wrapper around the GHC API designed for editors.