# How to compile Haskell into the untyped lambda calculus (or GHC core)?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, ghc-api

I'm looking for ways how to convert a simple Haskell program (no imported libraries, just data types and pure functions) into a term of the untyped lambda calculus. A promising approach seems to be to use [GHC API](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/) to compile a program into [GHC core](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/CoreSynType), which can be then converted into the untyped lambda calculus.

How to use GHC API to load a Haskell program and compile it into Core?

Comment: ghc has an option to output core - `ghc -ddump-simpl`. Also take a look at (ghc-core)[https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core], which basically just wraps `ddump-simpl` with some postprocessing.

Comment: @user2407038 That's true, but as I understand, ghc-core gives me a human-readable output that I'd further need to parse. Instead I'd like to get the core expression as a data structure to analyze it further. But it could be a good staring point, thanks.

Comment: That human-readable output also isn't designed to be parsed, and may not be terribly stable from version to version.

Comment: There are a [number of related attempts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bghc-api%5D+runGhc) at the core version of this question and attempted answers on stack overflow. One answer [appears to desugar a simple Haskell program into core](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2300839/414413) with an older version of ghc. A newer question asks [how to compile to core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059669/using-ghc-api-to-compile-haskell-sources-to-core-and-core-to-binary) and then from core to binary.

Comment: Untyped lambda calculus has only functions, no data. While you can encode data as functions, ghc cote won't help you in that.

Comment: @n.m. That's perfectly fine, I just want to get as close as possible to the untyped lambda calculus (core) and take over from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`GHC` module documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#g:6) in the ghc docs:

> `compileToCoreModule :: GhcMonad m => FilePath -> m CoreModule`
>
> This is the way to get access to the Core bindings corresponding to a
>   module. `compileToCore` parses, typechecks, and desugars the module,
>   then returns the resulting Core module (consisting of the module name,
>   type declarations, and function declarations) if successful.
>
> `compileToCoreSimplified :: GhcMonad m => FilePath -> m CoreModule`
>
> Like `compileToCoreModule`, but invokes the simplifier, so as to return
>   simplified and tidied Core.

I found this by looking through the list of `GHC` modules, noticing the [`Desugar`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/Desugar.html) module, noticing [`ModGuts`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/HscTypes.html#t:ModGuts) in the result of `deSugar`, downloading all of the documentation, and searching the text for `ModGuts`.

#### Minimal Example

Our example will compile a simple module so we can see what the core looks like. It uses [ghc-paths](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-paths) to provide the location of the ghc libs directory. The core will be represented in memory by a [`CoreModule`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#t:CoreModule) containing a list of [`CoreBind`s](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/CoreSyn.html#t:CoreBind). We can't dump the AST directly because there aren't `Show` instances for the AST described in `CoreSyn`, however the `Outputable` instance for `CoreModule` will pretty-print the core so we can see that we compiled to core.

```
import GHC
import DynFlags
import Outputable (Outputable, showPpr)
import qualified GHC.Paths as Paths

import Data.Functor
```

`runGhc'` takes care of all the setup needed for compiling to core a module with no `import`s and no `TemplateHaskell`. We completely turn off the linker with [`NoLink`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#t:GhcLink) and tell the compiler to produce nothing with [`HscNothing`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#t:HscTarget).

```
runGhc' :: Ghc a -> IO a
runGhc' ga = do
    runGhc (Just Paths.libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getDynFlags
        let dflags2 = dflags { ghcLink   = NoLink
                             , hscTarget = HscNothing
                             }
        setSessionDynFlags dflags2
        ga
```

Compiling a module to core consists of setting the target with [`guessTarget`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#v:guessTarget) and [`addTarget`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#v:addTarget), optionally loading dependencies with [`load`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#v:load), building the module graph with [`depanel`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#v:depanal), `find`ing the correct [`ModSummary`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#t:ModSummary) in the module graph, parsing the module with [`parseModule`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#v:parseModule), type checking it with [`typecheckModule`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#typecheckModule), desugarring it with [`desugarModule`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#v:desugarModule), converting it to [`ModGuts`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/HscTypes.html#t:ModGuts) with [`coreModule`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/GHC.html#v:coreModule) from the `DesugaredMod` instance for the result of desugarring, and extracting the core from the `ModGuts`. All of this is wrapped up in a nice package by [`compileToCoreModule`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/src/GHC.html#compileCore).

```
compileExample :: Ghc CoreModule
compileExample = compileToCoreModule "prettyPrint2dList.hs"
```

Our whole example program will output the core with [`showPpr`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc/Outputable.html#v:showPpr).

```
showPpr' :: (Functor m, Outputable a, HasDynFlags m) => a -> m String
showPpr' a = (flip showPpr) a <$> getDynFlags

main = runGhc' (compileExample >>= showPpr') >>= putStrLn
```

Compiling the above example requires the `-package ghc` flag to expose the normally hidden ghc api package.

The example module we'll compile to core, `"prettyPrint2dList.hs"`, contains a data type and a bit of code that uses functions from the prelude.

```
data X = Y | Z
         deriving (Eq, Show)

type R = [X]
type W = [R]

example = map (\x -> take x (cycle [Y, Z])) [0..]

main = undefined
```

Which produces a slew of pretty-printed core.

```
%module main:Main (Safe-Inferred) [01D :-> Identifier `:Main.main',
                                   a1f2 :-> Identifier `$c==', a1f5 :-> Identifier `$c/=',
                                   a1fb :-> Identifier `$cshowsPrec', a1fh :-> Identifier `$cshow',
                                   a1fk :-> Identifier `$cshowList',
                                   r0 :-> Identifier `Main.$fShowX', r1 :-> Identifier `Main.$fEqX',
                                   r2 :-> Type constructor `Main.R',
                                   r3 :-> Type constructor `Main.X', r4 :-> Identifier `Main.main',
                                   rqS :-> Type constructor `Main.W',
                                   rrS :-> Data constructor `Main.Y', rrV :-> Identifier `Main.Y',
                                   rrW :-> Data constructor `Main.Z', rrX :-> Identifier `Main.Z',
                                   rL2 :-> Identifier `Main.example']
Main.example :: [[Main.X]]
[LclIdX, Str=DmdType]
Main.example =
  GHC.Base.map
    @ GHC.Types.Int
    @ [Main.X]
    (\ (x :: GHC.Types.Int) ->
       GHC.List.take
         @ Main.X
         x
         (GHC.List.cycle
            @ Main.X
            (GHC.Types.:
               @ Main.X
               Main.Y
               (GHC.Types.: @ Main.X Main.Z (GHC.Types.[] @ Main.X)))))
    (GHC.Enum.enumFrom
       @ GHC.Types.Int GHC.Enum.$fEnumInt (GHC.Types.I# 0))
Main.main :: forall t. t
[LclIdX, Str=DmdType]
Main.main = GHC.Err.undefined
$cshowsPrec :: GHC.Types.Int -> Main.X -> GHC.Show.ShowS
[LclId, Str=DmdType]
$cshowsPrec =
  \ _ [Occ=Dead] (ds_d1gG :: Main.X) ->
    case ds_d1gG of _ [Occ=Dead] {
      Main.Y ->
        GHC.Show.showString
          (GHC.Types.:
             @ GHC.Types.Char
             (GHC.Types.C# 'Y')
             (GHC.Types.[] @ GHC.Types.Char));
      Main.Z ->
        GHC.Show.showString
          (GHC.Types.:
             @ GHC.Types.Char
             (GHC.Types.C# 'Z')
             (GHC.Types.[] @ GHC.Types.Char))
    }
Main.$fShowX [InlPrag=[ALWAYS] CONLIKE] :: GHC.Show.Show Main.X
[LclIdX[DFunId],
 Str=DmdType,
 Unf=DFun: \ ->
       GHC.Show.D:Show TYPE Main.X $cshowsPrec $cshow $cshowList]
Main.$fShowX =
  GHC.Show.D:Show @ Main.X $cshowsPrec $cshow $cshowList;
$cshowList [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: [Main.X] -> GHC.Show.ShowS
[LclId, Str=DmdType]
$cshowList =
  GHC.Show.showList__
    @ Main.X
    (GHC.Show.showsPrec @ Main.X Main.$fShowX (GHC.Types.I# 0));
$cshow [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Main.X -> GHC.Base.String
[LclId, Str=DmdType]
$cshow = GHC.Show.$dmshow @ Main.X Main.$fShowX;
$c== :: Main.X -> Main.X -> GHC.Types.Bool
[LclId, Str=DmdType]
$c== =
  \ (ds_d1gB :: Main.X) (ds_d1gC :: Main.X) ->
    let {
      fail_d1gD :: GHC.Prim.Void# -> GHC.Types.Bool
      [LclId, Str=DmdType]
      fail_d1gD = \ _ [Occ=Dead, OS=OneShot] -> GHC.Types.False } in
    case ds_d1gB of _ [Occ=Dead] {
      Main.Y ->
        case ds_d1gC of _ [Occ=Dead] {
          __DEFAULT -> fail_d1gD GHC.Prim.void#;
          Main.Y -> GHC.Types.True
        };
      Main.Z ->
        case ds_d1gC of _ [Occ=Dead] {
          __DEFAULT -> fail_d1gD GHC.Prim.void#;
          Main.Z -> GHC.Types.True
        }
    }
Main.$fEqX [InlPrag=[ALWAYS] CONLIKE] :: GHC.Classes.Eq Main.X
[LclIdX[DFunId],
 Str=DmdType,
 Unf=DFun: \ -> GHC.Classes.D:Eq TYPE Main.X $c== $c/=]
Main.$fEqX = GHC.Classes.D:Eq @ Main.X $c== $c/=;
$c/= [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: Main.X -> Main.X -> GHC.Types.Bool
[LclId, Str=DmdType]
$c/= =
  \ (a :: Main.X) (b :: Main.X) ->
    GHC.Classes.not (GHC.Classes.== @ Main.X Main.$fEqX a b);
:Main.main :: GHC.Types.IO GHC.Prim.Any
[LclIdX, Str=DmdType]
:Main.main =
  GHC.TopHandler.runMainIO
    @ GHC.Prim.Any (Main.main @ (GHC.Types.IO GHC.Prim.Any))
```